# How to check the datagridview not be empty?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I already tried this way but it is not working.

How do I fix it?

```
     if(dgvProducts.Rows.Count < 1 )
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Something");
         return;
     }
```

Comment: does your DGV is really an empty? if yes your code should work (more accurate code: `myDataGridView.Rows.Count == 0`)

Comment: Thank dear but it is still not working .. Can you tell me another way

Comment: Can you give more code please? sorry I wondered but it's looks like your DGV in not empty...

Comment: Do you have the datagridview setup so that the user is allowed to add rows? (`DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows property`) If yes there is always at least one row in the DataGridView (with the `DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow` property set to true)

Answer (score -2):

you may try something like this,

```
if(dgvProducts.Rows.Count > 1 )
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Something");
     return;
}
```

if it doesn't works then you may also try something like this too,

```
string nrCode = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
nrCode = nrCode.Trim();
if (nrCode == string.Empty)
{
MessageBox.Show("there must be Entry in cell nrCode on first row.")
}
```

the above code will allow you  to check if specific cell in first row in DataGridView is empty.

Hope it works.

Comment: And what if rows count == 1? And how do you know if there are 6 cells in a row? Even if it exists, value can be null and NullReferenceException will be thrown

Comment: @toddams i have just given him an idea to do it. as i have already implemented this kinnda situation in my application. And you may add '=' condition in code. Please make sure you first implement what has been mentioned. Thanks hawar khalid